# Column provided does not belong to this DataGridView control when calling Sort

Tags: sorting, datagridview

I have a `DataGridViewControl` with sortable columns. After editing data for one record in a row of this control, the list of records is refreshed and the `DataGridViewControl` gets updated:

```
m_Helper.UpdateRecord( some variables );
dgvMyData.DataSource = ReloadData();
```

Before I do that, I save `SortOrder` and the column which was used for sorting:

```
SortOrder sortOrder = dgvMyData.SortOrder;
DataGridViewColumn sortedColumn = dgvMyData.SortedColumn;
```

Now after reloading data I'd like to have the same sorting on the column selected beforehand, but I always end up with the error message

*Column provided does not belong to this DataGridView control*

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
ListSortDirection listSortDirection;
if ( sortOrder == SortOrder.Ascending )
{
    listSortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
}
else
{
    listSortDirection = ListSortDirection.Descending;
}

dgvMyData.Sort( sortedColumn, listSortDirection );
```

This always causes an `ArgumentException` with the error message shown above - I assume this happens because reloading the data for the `DataGridView` also causes the `DataGridViewColumn` to be a *different* one even though its called the same and contains the same type of data. How can I implement a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As assumed in my question, using the instance of sortedColumn directly doesn't work as it no longer part of the grid. I instead use the column's name like this:

```
if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( sortedColumn.Name ) && 
    dgvMyData.Columns[ sortedColumn.Name ] != null )
{
    dgvMyData.Sort(
        dgvMyData.Columns[ sortedColumn.Name ],
        listSortDirection );
}
```